# How to connect Amazon S3 to IBM datastage server which is hosted on premise

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, datastage

I have IBM Datastage server installed on premises.

I want to connect to an Amazon S3 bucket from datastage to load data.

How can i establish a connection to Amazon S3 from datastage server.

Answer (score 1):

From doing some online reading, the IBM product seems to work with a Java API.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.5?topic=connections-java-code

Therefore, you can use the AWS SDK for Java to invoke Amazon S3 operations. If you are not familiar with how to use the AWS SDK for Java (V2), see this doc topic:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, you may even have an S3 Connector stage available in your Palette.